# First Discord Bot

Tags: node.js

I am literally just trying to get this bot online first. It keeps throwing bitfield error. I am guessing I need to add permissions but not sure the best way to go about it.I am brand new to this.

> require('dotenv').config();
>
> const { Client,Intents,BitField} = require('discord.js'); const
> client= new Client({ intents: Intents.FLAGS.GUILDS});
> client.login(process.env.DISCORDJS_BOT_TOKEN);

ERROR:

RangeError [BITFIELD_INVALID]: Invalid bitfield flag or number: undefined.
at Function.resolve (C:\Users\tayla\documents\discord-bot\node_modules\discord.js\src\util\BitField.js:152:11)
at C:\Users\tayla\documents\discord-bot\node_modules\discord.js\src\util\BitField.js:147:54
at Array.map ()
at Function.resolve (C:\Users\tayla\documents\discord-bot\node_modules\discord.js\src\util\BitField.js:147:40)
at Client._validateOptions (C:\Users\tayla\documents\discord-bot\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\Client.js:550:33)
at new Client (C:\Users\tayla\documents\discord-bot\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\Client.js:76:10)
at Object. (C:\Users\tayla\documents\discord-bot\src\bot.js:4:15)
at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1101:14)
at Object.Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1153:10)
at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:981:32) {
[Symbol(code)]: 'BITFIELD_INVALID'
}

Answer (score 0):

Try putting `Intents.FLAGS.GUILDS` into an array as shown in the [documentation](https://discordjs.guide/popular-topics/intents.html#privileged-intents). `intents: [Intents.FLAGS.GUILDS]`